# Where can I download the twitterkit framework

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, twitter-fabric

I got the fabric framework through the fabric application. Even i tried to download the twitter kit framework on developer.twitter.com, nevertheless I couldn't get that framework. Anyone please ping your feed backs?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://get.fabric.io/
`For each Kit, we've completely streamlined the installation and upgrade process. Forget jumping through different SDK repos or downloading packages from multiple places -- we’ve done the heavy lifting for you.`

Answer (score 1):

You should install twitter framework [through CocoaPods](https://fabric.io/kits/ios/twitterkit/install)

Add bellow framework to your pod file, and follow instruction in the link above:

```
pod 'Fabric'
pod 'TwitterKit'
```